# jquery how to make function within document.ready

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to make a simple function to replace a ATTR when called with `onclick="changeYoutube('XXXXXX');"` in a link tag. However it is currently saying that calling "changeYoutube" is throwing a "Uncaught ReferenceError: changeYoutube is not defined" error.

```
            function changeYoutube(source) {

                    $('#youtube-viewport').attr('src', 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + source);

            }
```

**ENTIRE JS Core**

```
        // Control Header Size
        $(window).load(function() {

            var imageGrad = $('.image-grad'),
                image = $('#header-image-border img'),
                border = $('#header-image-border'),
                grad = $('#header-image-grad');

            function resizeDiv () {
                imageGrad.height(image.height());
                imageGrad.width($(window).width());
                border.css({'height': + image.height()});
            }

            resizeDiv();

            $(window).resize(function() { resizeDiv(); });

        });

        $(document).ready(function() {

            // Content Parser
            var contentQuery = './content.php';

            $('#background-overlay').fadeTo(1200, 1.0, function() {
                // Body loaded...
                $('#hi1').fadeTo(2000, 1.0, function() {
                    // Start Slides
                    var slide = 0,
                        ids = [
                            '#hi1',
                            '#hi2',
                            '#hi3',
                            '#hi4'
                            ],
                        count = ids.length;
                    slideShow = setInterval(function () {
                        var nextSlide = slide + 1;
                        if (nextSlide > count - 1) {
                            nextSlide = 0;
                        }
                        $(ids[slide]).fadeTo(600, 0);
                        $(ids[nextSlide]).fadeTo(2300, 1.0);
                        slide++;
                        if (slide > count - 1) {
                            slide = 0;
                        }
                    }, 20000);
                    // End Slides
                    // Slide Header Bar
                    $('#header-container').slideToggle('slow', function() {
                        // Load Containers
                        $('#boxes-container').fadeTo(1200, 1.0);
                        $('#footer-content').fadeTo(1200, 1.0);
                        // FadeIn Header Bar
                        $('#header').fadeTo('slow', 1.0, function() {
                            // Header loaded... start navigation load n' stuff
                            $('.logo').fadeTo(3000, 0.60, function() {
                                $('#icons-container img:first').fadeIn();
                                // Start Slides
                                var currentImage = $('#icons-container img:first');

                                setInterval(function(){
                                    currentImage.fadeOut();

                                    if(currentImage.next().size())
                                        currentImage = currentImage.next();
                                    else
                                        currentImage = currentImage.siblings().first();

                                    currentImage.fadeIn();
                                }, 5000);
                                // End Slides
                                });
                            $('#drop-ucp').slideToggle('slow');
                            (function fadeLink($){
                                $.eq(0).fadeTo(400, 0.50, function(){
                                    ($=$.slice(1)).length && fadeLink($);
                                });
                            })($('#navigation-list > li'));
                        });
                    });
                });
            });

            $('#navigation-list li').mouseenter(function(){
                $(this).fadeTo('slow', 1.0);
            });
            $('#navigation-list li').mouseout(function(){
                $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.60);
            })


            $('.logo').mouseenter(function(){
                $(this).fadeTo('slow', 1.0);
            });
            $('.logo').mouseout(function(){
                $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.60);
            });

            $('.search').click(function() {
                $('.search').val('');
            });

            $('.search').blur(function() {
                $('.search').val('Track Title / Game Title');
            });

            // Youtube Control              
            function changeYoutube(source) {

                    $('#youtube-viewport').attr('src', 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + source);

            }

        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically,you don't need to create a function inside `document.ready`.. replacing your function outside the `document.ready` function should work.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    ....
 }); //document.ready ends

 function changeYoutube(source) {
     $('#youtube-viewport').attr('src', 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + source);
 }
```

same goes for your `resizeDiv()` function too

Comment: Well the resize div function words, oddly enough. But thanks I didn't think the jquery would work outside the document/window tags.

Comment: for jquery to work , it doesn't have to be inside document/window function.. unless it is inside  `<script>..` tag...just that, keeping jquery codes inside document.ready function will make sure ,the jquery codes runs after all the elements in the document is ready... and yes most important.. `function ..()` is not jquery.. it is plain javascript for creating an anonymos function :)...

Comment: Definitely, but the way the resize function is setup it needs the dynamic content within the window tag.

Comment: then you can keep it inside the load function... read more about javascript function closure .. :).. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Closures ..